# SQL most efficient way to check if rows from one table are also present in another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two DB tables each containing email addresses

```
One is mssql with 1.500.000.000 entries
One is mysql with    70.000.000 entries
```

I now want to check how many identical email addresses are present in both tables.
i.e. the same address is present in both tables.

Which approach would be the fastest:
1. Download both datasets as csv, load it into memory and compare in program code
2. Use the DB queries to get the overlapping resultset.

if 2 is better: What would be a suggested SQL query?

Comment: Are the tables on the same DB?

Comment: Fastest depends on many things. Like, how well are the records indexed, how fast can you code the in-memory solution, is the DB being used in production right now?

Comment: Are the email addresses in one table a subset of the email addresses in the other, or are there going to be emails in each one that are not in the other?

Comment: @JakeSteele probably not as they are mysql and mssql.

Comment: If you want option 2 are you going to set up a linked server?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a DBQuery. Set up a linked server connection between the two DBs (probably on the MSSQL side), and use a simple inner join query to produce the list of e-mails that occur in both tables:

```
select a.emailAddress
from MSDBServ.DB.dbo.Table1 a
join MySqlServ.DB..Table2 b
    on a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
```

Finding the set difference, that's going to take more processor power (and it's going to produce at least 1.4b results in the best-case scenario of every MySql row matching an MSSQL row), but the query isn't actually that much different. You still want a join, but now you want that join to return all records from both tables whether they could be joined or not, and then you specifically want the results that aren't joined (in which case one side's field will be null):

```
select a.EmailAddress, b.EmailAddress
from MSDBServ.DB.dbo.Table1 a
full join MySqlServ.DB..Table2 b
    on a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
where a.EmailAddress IS NULL OR b.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: I agree. If a linked server is not an option, you could import the MySql table into the MS Sql database and run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Table1 has the 70,000,000 email addresses, table2 has the 1,500,000,000.  I use Oracle so the Upper function may or may not have an equivalent in MySQL.

```
Select EmailAddress from table1 where Upper(emailaddress) in (select Upper(emailaddress) from table2)
```

Quicker than comparing spreadsheets and this assumes both tables are in the same database.

Comment: You would not use UPPER() as SQL Server is not case sensitive by default so 'ABC'='abc'.

Comment: Not that familiar with Sql Server, but he's using MySQL, don't know if there is an equivalent in MySQL or if, like Sql Serve, it doesn't matter.  With Oracle, case matters.

Comment: Case sensitivity in sql server is based on collation. The default is case insensitive but there are plenty of people that use case sensitive collations. That will depend and vary on the users situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a sql query to check how many identical email addresses are present in two databases: first number is how many duplicates, second value is the email address.

```
SELECT COUNT(emailAddr),emailAddr FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN
table2 B
ON A.emailAddr = B.emailAddr
```

Comment: You're missing a Group By clause; both MSSQL and MySQL will complain if there's a mix of single fields and aggregates with no Group By clause for the single fields.